# Joint law of a fBm which starts with a given random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let us consider the fractional brownian motion $B_t^H, H \in (0,1)$ with mean zero and covariance function given by 
$$
\frac{1}{2} (t^{2H} + s^{2H} - |t-s|^{2H}),
$$
taking values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let us consider a random variable $X$ independent from the fBm with, for instance, uniform law. Let us define the following process $\tilde{B}_t^H = B_t^H + X$.

I need to compute the following quantity for a Borel function $f$ 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left \vert \int_0^t f (\tilde{B}_s^H) \ ds\right \vert^2\right].
\end{equation}
My first attempt was to obtain a kernel, essentially the joint law of the process $\tilde{B}_t^H$ such that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left \vert \int_0^t f (\tilde{B}_s^H) \ ds\right \vert^2\right]= \int_\mathbb{R}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_0^t \int_0^t f (x) f(y) K(x,y,t,s) \ dx \ dy \ ds \ dt.
$$
However, I wanted to use a property of stationarity for this process, but in the case $H= \frac{1}{2}$ this is false.

Which can be a good approach or what are some way to estimate the quantity above.

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to be independent of the fractional Brownian motion?

Comment: Yes, I should have been more precise. It's because of the independence assumption that the stationarity approach seemed to me a good choice.